# Can we ask MSDN to stop redirecting SQL Server 2016 user feedback to StackOverflow?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question, scope, outsourcing

The [page here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156511(v=sql.130).aspx) states

> Be sure to share your feedback on the new SQL Server 2016 capabilities
>   on www.stackoverflow.com.

Someone [has done so](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32441631/73226).

I've voted to close as off topic. Unless I missed a change of policy this is not an appropriate venue for "sharing feedback".

Was this the correct action? If so perhaps someone from Stack Exchange should get in touch with them to amend the text.

Comment: Entirely correct; I've closed the question.

Comment: `SELECT TOP KEK;`

Comment: I've sent in "Community Addition" feedback on the MSDN page.

Comment: @MSalters - Hopefully someone monitors that and can make the necessary edit then.

Comment: @MartinSmith: I've raised issues before and received emails in response. I have a positively ancient .Net Passport account, though, don't know if that helps.

Comment: I said this was an unhelpful page and added a comment

Comment: I'm surprised a 20k user does this.

Comment: @Emrakul If you are removing "Reach Out" here's some more for you http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22reach+out%22+is%3Aquestion

Comment: @MartinSmith Thanks :] I edited it so that what the question is about would be clearer from the sidebar, so the other ones are a lower priority, but I'll save them for a future point.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I'm reaching out to Microsoft now. As they're a giant company, it can be tedious to locate the key people you need to change something, but I'm working on it.

It's a good reminder of just how unique we are, six years and over 10 million questions later, people still don't often immediately recognize our purpose and criteria :)

Helpful comments such as:

> *We're sorry, the link you followed from MSDN set your expectations erroneously, we're only for objective Q&A for very specific programming questions, not a general discussion forum. Please file a bug report at MSDN with a link to your question here so the admins become aware of the disconnect.*

.. or something equally helpful that doesn't chide the user for just doing what they thought Microsoft wanted them to do. This has happened in the past with Azure and was quickly resolved, but MSDN appears to be an entirely different group of people, so I'm off to figure out who they are and say hello.

Said people can obviously contact me directly if they're reading this, I'm `tpost@stackoverflow.com` (feel free to also link to my answer if you happen to know anyone that could help).

**Update**

[They're looking into it](https://twitter.com/danielfe/status/641256569003372545). I'll see what I can do to help :)

**Update update**

[We're all set!](https://twitter.com/danielfe/status/641623904813867008) Thank you [Dan!](https://twitter.com/danielfe) They deserve some applause, here - what we feared would be an uphill struggle was actually resolved with just a few tweets. They've got some great people working there.

Comment: "Six years"? 2008-07-31 is more than 7 years ago. Unless you are counting from some other date...

Comment: @NormalHuman: for me personally, everything older than 2 weeks is so blurry. 3 months or 3 years - not much of a difference :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev You said that a whole six _hours_ ago? What are you getting on about? Oh look, a kite!!!!

Comment: In the SQL Server tags there are Microsofties giving real answers, btw. Especially Azure. This has started a few month ago. Must be an initiative.

Comment: The page has been updated, and someone from Microsoft left this comment: "I can see why you might interpret the previous text the way you did.  That was not the intent and the text has been updated.  Thanks for the feedback!"

Comment: @Jan Fabry: Should have posted it on SO.

Comment: @BoltClock Stop; someone will believe you

Answer (score 11):

Notably, "please post about our CTP on StackOverflow" isn't completely meaningless... some companies try to enforce a cone of silence on prerelease software, even publicly available ones (particularly things like banning posting benchmark results).

It's good that Microsoft is explicitly encouraging the community to talk about their CTP. That said, the usual Stack Overflow rules for topicality still apply, and bug reports or questions about future plans are off-topic here.

Beyond that, most aspects of SQL Server usage would be better on some of our sister sites, like [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/), [Super User](https://superuser.com/), or [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/). Only questions about writing code to interact with SQL Server could be appropriate here.

Comment: Don't forget about [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/)!

Comment: @KennyEvitt: Thanks, I added that to the list.

Answer (score 6):

It appears that two people left a comment on [the page in question](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156511(v=sql.130).aspx) and someone from Microsoft responded with:

> I can see why you might interpret the previous text the way you did.  That was not the intent and the text has been updated.  Thanks for the feedback! -Craig

The text has been updated.

Answer (score 4):

## They fixed it!

https://twitter.com/danielfe/status/641623904813867008:

> @GBrayUT @tinkertim Just a quick heads up that we've since removed that and added the SO link to the "Need help?" section

Comment: The tag info at the top seems to be just enough guidance. Yay! I'm really impressed with how well they responded.